# waiting for apiserver: timed out waiting for the condition[kubernetes]

Tags: docker, kubernetes, proxy, virtualbox

i ran the minikube start in windows 10 and i got this error,i totally installed the minikube and virtualbox and kubectl .

```
-->>minikube start 
* minikube v1.2.0 on windows (amd64)
* Tip: Use 'minikube start -p <name>' to create a new cluster, or 'minikube delete' to delete this one.
* Re-using the currently running virtualbox VM for "minikube" ...
* Waiting for SSH access ...
* Found network options:
  - NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,10.96.0.0/12,192.168.99.1/24,192.168.39.0/24
* Configuring environment for Kubernetes v1.15.0 on Docker 18.09.6
  - env NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,10.96.0.0/12,192.168.99.1/24,192.168.39.0/24
* Relaunching Kubernetes v1.15.0 using kubeadm ...

X Error restarting cluster: waiting for apiserver: timed out waiting for the condition

* Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new
```

```
-->minikube status
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Stopped
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.101
```

if there is a way to handle this problem please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things you should try:

1. You might not be waiting long enough for the apiserver to become healthy. Increase apiserver wait time.
2. Use different version of Minikube. Remember to run `minikube delete` to remove the previous cluster state.
3. If your environment is behind a proxy than setup a correct `NO_PROXY` env. More about this can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/http_proxy.md).
4. use minikube delete then minikube start

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: thanks, it seems to i had problem with proxy, i use vpn to connect, this made a problem to apiserver